# Insert into ListBox from a Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, listbox, listboxitem

**Question:** How can I insert items into a listbox from a database?

Here is what I tried:

```
    public void Fetch()
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(UtilObj.ConnectionString()))
        {
            cn.Open();
            ExecuteFetch(cn);
            cn.Close();
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteFetch(SqlConnection cn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cm.CommandText = "spName";
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", Param1Val);
            using (SafeDataReader dr = new SafeDataReader(cm.ExecuteReader()))
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    myListBox.Items.Add(dr["Color"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This shows an empty list when I run the code even though it populates in debugger.

ASPX Page

```
<asp:ListBox ID="myListBox" runat="server" />
```

Comment: You declared listbox as local variable! are you adding in different listbox?

Comment: To extend Sriram's question, why are you defining your ListBox in code rather than having one already placed on the form via the Designer? If you don't want to do it that way, you still have to add it to your form.

Comment: No, that is probably my problem. When I remove that it says The name 'myListBox' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Do you have a main form? Try saying `this.Controls.Add(myListBox)` (assuming Winforms)

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question with the other information. Was hoping I just made a simple mistake in the code behind.

Comment: Still having same issue, it shows in the debugger, but not on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:-

Get reader object after executing your sp

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

myListBox.DataSource= reader; //reader object
myListBox.DataTextField = "Color"; // the field you want to show in listbox
myListBox.DataValueField = "Color"; // the value filed behind the items. 
myListBox.Databind();
```

Text and Value Fields can be same as well if you want it that way

That's it. It's the same way you bind items to a dropdown list. Just used this in our recent project

Hope it's helpful

Comment: Well, the way I'm doing it shows when I look in the debugger that it contains 1 item and what that item is, but when I run the code it does not display it.

Comment: Add this to your list box tag:- <asp:ListBox ID="myListBox" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"/> Also check the above code I've edited it. I mean have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry, still did not work. I'm going to try to make a new project and see if maybe my current project is just being stubburn.